# Check all checkboxes on checkbox click jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a jquery datatable I added  a checkbox in the header. I want all the checkboxes in my tbody to be checked when the checkbox in the header is checked and unchecked when the checkbox in the header is unchecked.

Here is my jquery datatable

```
<div style="width:100%; margin:0 auto" class="tablecontainer">
    <table id="tblProveedorToTransfert" class="display nowrap" style="width: 100%;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><input id="chkAll" name="select_all" value="1" type="checkbox"></th>
                <th>Proveedor</th>
                <th>Precio unitario</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
```

Here is the code when the checkbox in the header is checked.

```
    $('#chkAll').click(function () {
        if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
            primaryTable.rows().every(function (rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop) {
                var data_row = this.data();

                secondTable.row.add({
                    "compras_id": data_row.compras_id,
                    "nombre_proveedor": data_row.nombre_proveedor,
                    "numero_contrato": data_row.numero_contrato,
                    "numero_pedido": data_row.numero_pedido,
                    "marca": data_row.marca,
                    "designacion": data_row.designacion,
                    "tipo": data_row.tipo,
                    "referencia": data_row.referencia,
                    "plazo": data_row.plazo,
                    "cantidad_requerida": data_row.cantidad_requerida,
                    "cantidad_pedida": data_row.cantidad_pedida,
                    "precio_unitario": data_row.precio_unitario,
                }).draw();
                rowsIDs.push(data_row.compras_id);
            });
            //check all the checkboxes in the jquery datatable
        }
        else
        {
            rowsIDs = [];
            primaryTable.rows().every(function (rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop) {
                var data_row = this.data();
                secondTable.row("#" + data_row.compras_id).remove().draw();
            });
            //uncheck all the checkboxes in the jquery datatable
        }
    });
```

And here is part of how my columns are made

```
                "columns": [
                    {
                        "width": "40px", "render": function (data, type, row) { /* index = 0 */
                            return '';
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "width": "10px", "render": function (data, type, row) { /* index = 0 */
                            return '<input value="0" type="checkbox" class="checkbox"  name="comprasIds" id="comprasIds" data-id="' + row.compras_id + '"  />';
                        }
                    },
                    { "data": "nombre_proveedor", "autoWidth": true }, /* index = 0 */
],
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Create a snippet and I'll gladly take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
  var rows = table.rows().nodes();
  $('input[type="checkbox"]', rows).prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: I am not using the standard jquery checkbox datatables so it will not work in my case.